# Use Javascript to apply CSS property of fontWeight to label tag of radio button

Tags: javascript, forms, input, radio-button, label

I have searched the Internet looking for a solution, and I've reached my wit's end. I've been experimenting with Javascript for a few weeks now, but for the life of me I can't manage to make this new project work.

My initial goal is to bold all the correct answers for an online quiz I've been developing for one of my classes. I can bold the correct answers using CSS easily enough, marked with a class name of "Correct", but I can't make Javascript execute a command to do the same at the click of a button.

If anyone could help me solve this issue it would be much appreciated. The ClearCorrectAnswers() function is meant to reverse the effects of ShowCorrectAnswers().

The javascript I've been developing can be found below:

```
function ShowCorrectAnswers() {
    var correctAnswers = document.getElementsByClassName("Correct");

    for (var count = 0; count < correctAnswers.length; count++) {
        correctAnswers[count].style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
}

function ClearCorrectAnswers() {
    var correctAnswers = document.getElementByClassName("Correct");

    for (var count = 0; count < correctAnswers.length; count++) {
        correctAnswers[count].style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}
```

The HTML can likewise be found below:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Test" onClick="ComputeGrade()">
<button type="button" onClick="ShowCorrectAnswers()">Show Correct Answer</button>
<button type="button" onClick="ClearCorrectAnswers">Clear Correct Answer</button>
<p>1. The external behavior of a system is described by _____.
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="As1" value="1">
    <label class="Correct">A. functional models</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="As1" value="0">
    <label>B. structural models</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="As1" value="0">
    <label>C. behavioral models</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="4" name="As1" value="0">
    <label>D. interaction diagrams</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="5" name="As1" value="0">
    <label>E. statechart diagrams</label>
</p>
<p>2. An analyst depicts the static view of an information system with _____.
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="As2" value="0">
    <label>
        <label>A. use-case models</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="As2" value="1">
        <label class="Correct">B. structural models</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="As2" value="0">
        <label>C. behavioral models</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="As2" value="0">
        <label>D. interaction diagrams</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="As2" value="0">
        <label>E. statechart diagrams</label>
</p>
<p>3. The two types of interaction diagrams are ______________ diagrams.
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="0">
    <label>A. use-case and sequence</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="0">
    <label>B. class and sequence</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="1">
    <label class="Correct">C. sequence and communication</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="0">
    <label>D. object and communication</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="0">
    <label>E. statechart and object</label>
</p>
```

Comment: You should use script to add and remove the "Correct" class as appropriate. Do you want help with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function ShowCorrectAnswers() {
    var correctAnswers = document.getElementsByClassName("Correct");

    for (var count = 0; count < correctAnswers.length; count++) {
        correctAnswers[count].style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
}

function ClearCorrectAnswers() {

    var correctAnswers = document.getElementsByClassName("Correct");

    for (var count = 0; count < correctAnswers.length; count++) {
        correctAnswers[count].style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}
</script>
```

and HTML :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Test" onClick="ComputeGrade()">
<button type="button" onClick="ShowCorrectAnswers()">Show Correct Answer</button>
<button type="button" onClick="ClearCorrectAnswers()">Clear Correct Answer</button>

<p>1. The external behavior of a system is described by _____.<br>
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="As1" value="1"><label class="Correct"> A. functional models</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="As1" value="0"><label> B. structural models</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="As1" value="0"><label> C. behavioral models</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="4" name="As1" value="0"><label> D. interaction diagrams</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="5" name="As1" value="0"><label> E. statechart diagrams</label>
</p>


<p>2. An analyst depicts the static view of an information system with _____.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="As2" value="0"><label><label> A. use-case models</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="As2" value="1"><label class="Correct"> B. structural models</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="As2" value="0"><label> C. behavioral models</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="As2" value="0"><label> D. interaction diagrams</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="As2" value="0"><label> E. statechart diagrams</label>
</p>

<p>3. The two types of interaction diagrams are ______________ diagrams.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="0"><label> A. use-case and sequence</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="0"><label> B. class and sequence</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="1"><label class="Correct"> C. sequence and communication</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="0"><label> D. object and communication</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="As3" value="0"><label> E. statechart and object</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off doing the hard work in CSS, and just toggling a parent class once, rather than going through every single `.correct` label.

So, assuming you have this HTML:

```
<form id="quiz">
    ...
</form>
```

You'd have this CSS somewhere:

```
<style>
#quiz.showAnswers .correct {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
<script>
function showCorrectAnswers () {
    document.getElementById('quiz').className = 'showAnswers';
}

function clearCorrectAnswers () {
    document.getElementById('quiz').className = '';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Of course, if everything is being handled client-side, you don't necessarily need that wrapper to be a `form` - could just as well be a `div`, or the entire `body`.